# javax.faces.FacesException: Target model Type is no a Collection or Array

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When submitting a JSF form, I'm getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Target model Type is no a Collection or Array 
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:388) [:2.0.3-] 
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:125) [:2.0.3-] 
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:311) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1023) [:2.0.3-]     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:953) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1204) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:693) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:240) [:2.0.3-] 
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$3.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:439) [:3.3.1.GA] 
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:238) [:3.3.1.GA] 
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processValidators(AjaxViewRoot.java:455) [:3.3.1.GA] 
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:72) [:2.0.3-]   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-] 
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-] 
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 42 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: It's impossible to solve this with just a stack trace - we don't know what component is wired to what model. Create a reduced code sample that manifests this bug. E.g. a JSF page (and backing bean) with only the one-two components from your actual code that cause the same error to appear. (Basically, take your code and start deleting stuff that's not related to the error. When you can't delete anything else without making the bug not appear anymore, that's your reduced sample.)

Comment: It would be better to provide some source code than this 1km long stack trace. We just see that you didn't provided right property in backing bean for a `selectMenu` component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Target model Type is no a Collection or Array
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:388)
```

This exception indicates that you've an `UISelectMany` component in the view such as `<h:selectManyMenu>` or `<h:selectManyListbox>` whose value is **not** been bound to a collection or array. This is not right. Its value must be bound to a collection (like `List<Entity>`) or array (like `Entity[]`), because the component can retrieve multiple submitted values.

Here's a kickoff example of how a proper `<h:selectManyMenu>` look like, assuming that you're using `String` typed items:

```
<h:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

with

```
private List<String> selectedItems; // Note: List<String> and thus NOT String!
private List<String> availableItems;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableItems = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
}

public void submit() {
    System.out.println("Selected items: " + selectedItems);
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to get all the selected values from h:selectManyListbox in the backend bean in case of JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358326/how-to-get-all-the-selected-values-from-hselectmanylistbox-in-the-backend-bean/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was: I removed the attribute "dtSubItem" from the tag `process` of the  `<p:commandButton>` tag and all works normally. The command button was submitting the datatable on the submit event.

Worked on the first request, but at the second the error emerged, when datatable was populated.

```html
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-2">
  <div class="espacoCampo">
      <p:outputLabel value=""  />  
          <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{managedBean.adicionarSubItemPanel(item)}"
                update="dtSubItem"
                title="Clique aqui para adicionar SubItem"
                icon="fa fa-plus"
                value="Adicionar"
                process="@this dtSubItem cadSubItens"
                iconPos="right"
                 >
      </p:commandButton>
    </div>
</div>


<p:dataTable var="subItem" id="dtSubItem" emptyMessage="Sem registros adicionados" value="#{item.btpResolucaoItemSubitemList}">
...
</p:dataTable>
```